# How to style InputLabel & Select on an AppBar?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

Still very new to Material-UI. Using the default theme/colors, I want to create an `AppBar` that has a `FormControl`/`InputLabel`/`Select`/`MenuItem` in it. With the defaults, I get a black input field on blue, which isn't great. I think probably having the input field and labels be `theme.palette.primary.light` would make more sense. I started to look in to how to do this and got in to setting `FormLabelClasses` to the `InputLabel`, setting `inputProps` to `Select` to set `classes` on the icon, and setting `&:before` and `&:after` to borders on the `Select` and so on... I feel like I'm doing this wrong since that seems to be quite a bit of work for something I think would be somewhat normal to do? To top it off, it's still not right (when you hover, the underline border goes black and I can't figure out how to fix that!)

Here's my code:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    minWidth: 200,
    marginTop: '-10px',
  },
  inputLabel: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.light,
    '&$inputLabelFocused': {
      color: theme.palette.primary.light,
    },
  },
  inputLabelFocused: {
  },
  icon: {
    fill: theme.palette.primary.light,
  },
  select: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.light,
    '&:before': {
      borderColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
    },
    '&:after': {
      borderColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
    },
  },
})

class CustomSelector extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return(
      <div>
        <FormControl className={classes.root}>
          <InputLabel FormLabelClasses={{ root: classes.inputLabel, focused: classes.inputLabelFocused }}>Choose</InputLabel>
          <Select value="" className={classes.select} inputProps={{ classes: { icon: classes.icon } }} autoWidth="true">
            <MenuItem value=""><em>None</em></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Value 1">Value 1</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```